# Fields "Created" and "Modified" in Document Properties (PDF) were not displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymupdf, python-pdfreader

Currently I have merged many PDFs together to create one PDF together. I have added metadata information which includes two fields "Created" and "Modified" but as a result these fields still do not display information.
Here's my source code:

```
import re
import os
import fitz
from datetime import datetime

def importMetaData(path):
    regex = r"^r20ut(\d+)ej(\d+)$"
    r_UM = re.compile(regex)
    extension = [".pdf"]
    now = datetime.now() # current date and time
    date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
    print("date and time:",date_time)
    Number = ""
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
            f_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            if ext in extension:
                if r_UM.search(f_name) is not None:
                    if root.endswith("thuan1"):
                        Number = dictRNumber["code1"]
                    elif root.endswith("thuan2"):
                        Number = dictRNumber["code2"]
                    else:
                        continue
                    inforPDF=fitz.open(os.path.join(root, file))
                    inforPDF.set_metadata({})
                    inforPDF.set_metadata(
                    {
                        "producer": "Microsoft® Word for Office 365",
                        "author": "Thuan",
                        "modDate": date_time,
                        "title": "Data Analysis",
                        "creationDate": date_time,
                        "creator": "Microsoft® Word for Office 365",
                        "subject": Number
                    })
                    inforPDF.save(os.path.join(root, f_name+".pdf"))
```

Image

[image]

Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Why are you calling `set_metadata()` twice in a row? Remove the first call that sets it to empty: `inforPDF.set_metadata({})`.

Comment: @martineau -san,command line  inforPDF.set_metadata({}) is used to  clear all fields. You can refer to section set_metadat() Example (https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document.set_metadata)

Comment: OK. From the documentation it sounds like in the second call you would need to pass the function a dictionary that is an updated version of what's in `inforPDF.metadata` after you've cleared it.

Comment: From the merged file from many of those files, I converted to word and then re-exported the PDF, the two fields were inputted. I don't really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the maintainer of PyMuPDF.

It is indeed not necessary to first clear the metadata before they get filled with the ultimately desired values.

More importantly, there is a PDF-specific datetime format **which must be used** to ensure all PDF viewers understand it: `D:20210207070439-03'00'`.

Also, there is a function in PyMuPDF which delivers the correct value for the current timestamp: `fitz.getPDFnow()`.

Comment: Please also check out the issue opened in the repo's home page https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/887